# Add Categorical Column with Specific Count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new categorical column of countries with specific percentage values. Take the following dataset, for instance:

```
df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
```

I'm trying the following script to get the new column:

```
country = ['UK', 'Ireland', 'France']

df["country"] = np.random.choice(country, len(df))

df["country"].value_counts(normalize=True)

UK         0.344557
Ireland    0.328844
France     0.326599
```

However, I'm getting all the countries with equal count. I want specific count for each country:

**Desired Output**

```
df["country"].value_counts(normalize=True)

UK         0.91
Ireland    0.06
France     0.03
```

What would be the ideal way of getting the desired output? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you want this distribution (not exact numbers) you can use [`p` argument of `np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to change the probabilities of [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)?

```
df["country"] = np.random.choice(country, len(df), p=[0.91, 0.06, 0.03])
df["country"].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Output:

```
UK         0.902357
Ireland    0.058361
France     0.039282
Name: country, dtype: float64
```

If you want a exact number of values (within the limit of the precision):

```
p = [0.91, 0.06, 0.03]
r = (np.array(p)*len(df)).round().astype(int) # the sum MUST be equal to len(df)
# or
# r = [811,  53,  27]

a = np.repeat(country, r)
np.random.shuffle(a)

df['country'] = a

df["country"].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Output:

```
UK         0.910213
Ireland    0.059484
France     0.030303
Name: country, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway. Appreciate. I have another question -- if I want to sample the dataset with the same country percentage value, how would i do that? I tried ```df.sample(frac=0.20, weights='country')```

Comment: `df.groupby('country').sample(frac=0.2)`?